# Low Search not finding three letter words

Tags: ee2, search, low-search

All three letter words using Low Search are not showing in results yet are showing when I use the native EE search.

These are words such as "Air" or "Ten" which appear in the entry title.
These words appear in the Lexicon and the title has a weight of 3.

*Form tag:*
{exp:low_search:form result_page='search/lowsearch' collection='products'}

*Results Tag:*
{exp:low_search:results query='{segment_3}' collection='products' keywords:lang='en'}

*Details:*
EE: 2.9.2
Low Search: 4.4.1
Collection: products
Min word length: 3

[image: Lexicon search]

[image: Collection settings]

[image: Low Search Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Minimum word length* setting has to reflect your MySQL's `ft_min_word_len` setting. This defaults to 4. Some people, who have complete control over their hosting environment, can change this setting to a lower number, but most of the time, the default value is accurate. If you set the value to a different (specifically lower) number than is registered in MySQL, then unexpected results can happen. If you haven't customized your MySQL installation, then chances are that setting still has the default value.

Low Search's collection index uses MySQL's native full-text functions to get search results for keyword searches. MySQL's full-text index only indexes words that are of the `ft_min_word_len` and up. So, by default, 4 characters and up; 3 and below are ignored. That means searching for words that are 3 chars and below would return no results. This is why LS fires an alternative search method (based on `LIKE`) when it sees the keywords fall below the threshold. However, if the *Minimum word length* in LS is set to 3 while it's actually 4 in MySQL, the regular search method will fire with 3-letter words, and consequently will return no results.

tl;dr: change your *Minimum word length* setting back to 4.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. That will teach me to play with something without understanding it.